# Integrate out missing variables in Gaussian Processing?

Tags: missing-data, gaussian-process

In https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/103533/83252 @juampa writes

> [...] in models like Naive Bayes or Gaussian Processes you would integrate out missing variables, and choose the best option with the remaining variables.

What does (s)he mean by that? How do I use Gaussian Processing Regression on incomplete datasets, "integrating out" the missing variables?

I am mostly interested in a detailed (hopefully step by step, easy to understand) mathematical explanation.

Answer (score 6):

The linked question is discussing data imputation for the purposes of building a predictive model. What I believe the accepted answer is referring to is using a Gaussian Process as a model for the missing data, conditional on the observed data.

"Integrating out" these missing variables then means marginalising the predictions of the resulting *predictive* model (the model built using these "imputed" data points) over the distribution of possible values the missing points could take.

I am not confident enough to give you a *rigorous* mathematical explanation, but I will attempt a verbose, intuitive example since this has been open for a while, and perhaps someone else can expand on it or correct me if I also misunderstand.

---

Suppose we wish to build a predictive model of some function $f(x,y,z)$, but the process by which we collect data on variable $z$ is messy. So sometimes we will only have access to $x$ and $y$.

In order to build our predictive model, we require $z$. One approach is to attempt to "impute" $z$, given it's previous observations *and* any covariance structure we believe might be present between $x$, $y$ and $z$: this is where we can use a Gaussian Process.

In this case, we suppose a Gaussian Process models $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. To make things a bit easier to read, assume we concatenate $x$ and $y$ into a vector, $r$ (so $r:=[x, y]$). We consequently end up with a set of different $r$ corresponding to all the data points we have collected.

For some of these datapoints, there will not be a corresponding measurement $z$ (as it was corrupted, is missing, or otherwise unavailable). If we refer to these points ($x$ and $y$ measurements missing a particular $z$) as $r^*$, and the missing values as $z^*$, our task is to compute $z^*$ at $r^*$ *conditional* on $r$ and $z$.

Using a Gaussian Process we can do this as follows:

Let $k$ be some appropriate covariance kernel and $\theta$ its hyperparameters, and let $\mathbf{z}$ be the stacked vector of *observed* $z$ (so those $z$ measurements we do have). Additionally, I will use the somewhat abusive notation of $k(a,b)$ to represent the covariance **matrix** obtained by evaluating $k$ pairwise between the elements of $a$ and $b$.

**Note**:
*If you're unfamiliar with [how to pick a kernel](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/) or how to identify the hyperparameters, I suggest reading some of the introductory material on Gaussian Processes - I won't cover it here in the interest of brevity. I personally like this three part ([1](https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/gp_part1/part1.html),[2](https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/gp_part2/part2.html),[3](https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/gp_part3/part3.html)) series by Michael Betancourt.*

The predictive distribution of $z^*$ is a multivariate normal distribution conditional on the currently observed values $z$, the points at which they are observed, $r$, the kernel $k$, and the kernel hyperparameters $\theta$:

$p(z^* | r, z, k, \theta) \sim \mathrm{MultiNormal} (\mu_p, \Sigma_p)$

where the "predictive" (or conditional) mean distribution $\mu_p$ is given by:

$\mu_p = k(r^*,r) [k(r, r)]^{-1} \mathbf{z}$

And the predictive covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is:

$\Sigma = k(r^*, r^*) - k(r^*, r) [k(r, r)]^{-1} k(r,r^*)$

Given this model for $p(z^* | r, z, k, \theta)$, we are able to assess the probability of $z^*$ given the observed data and the assumptions we used to select $k$.

---

Now, suppose we want to use these imputed values of $z^*$ in a predictive model for some other quantity $f(x,y,z)$: **It is here we would "integrate out" missing variables.**

Since our predictions of $z^*$ are a *distribution* (a normal distribution, $p(z^*)$, given we have used a Gaussian Process as a model for $z$), we probably want to capture uncertainty in the fact we do not know $z$ at these locations exactly.

Very simply, if we want to make a prediction of $f(x,y,z)$ using $x, y$ and $p(z^*)$, we should account for all the values $z^*$ *could* be when making this prediction. This amounts to approaching the following integral:

$p(f(x,y,z^*)) = \displaystyle\int f(x,y,z^*) p(z^*) dz^*$

This is usually approached numerically since $f$ rarely permits an analytical treatment (but it might). Typical approaches are quadrature or Monte-Carlo simulation.

The important point is that predictions made *using* $z^*$ are done so over the distribution of possible $z^*$. This implies these predictions are themselves a distribution, and should be assessed as such to evaluate predictive performance in a robust way,