How Random Forest handle missing value in sk-learn?
What is the technic used in Random Forest Regressor from scikit-learn to handle missing value ?
First I thought that a Random Forest regressor was able to natively handle missing value during training and production, without loosing any accuracy (sklearn doc, sklearn changelog v1.4, stack question).
Therefore, I used the RandomForestResgressor from scikit-learn, on data with a huge amount of Missing Value (see image below).
It's working, but now, after some research, it seems to me that the Random Forest model does not handle Missing Value natively, but that libraries use various techniques such as imputation/knn/Miss Forest/etc. to handle Missing Value.
This question present the different possibilities to handle Missing value in a RF, but I would like to know how scikit-learn is dealing with missing value in their implementation of RandomForestRegressor.
My goal will be to understand whether it's okay to have a large amount of missing value, and that it will not decrease the accuracy, or whether it's better to clean most of them upstream (removing observations and features with a lot of missing value).

My example:
Each column is a feature, and each row is an observation. Black are value, white are missing value. We see for example that the 4 features on the right are present only in few observations. I let them, thinking that for observation where these features are present, it will improve the accuracy, and if not, RandomForest will just not use this feature.     However, depending on how Random Forest handle missing value, it may be preferable to remove these features before training the model.


There appears to be an answer to your question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/98953/why-doesnt-random-forest-handle-missing-values-in-predictors

This question is similar to: Why doesn't Random Forest handle missing values in predictors?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (FYI @statneutrino, this is an autogenerated message for close votes, nice find!)

Thx for the comments. I saw this question, that is explaing that RF can handle missing value using different technics. But I want to know which technic is used by sk-learn, and if missing value will impact negatively the model accuracy.

You already have your answer: it cannot handle them and it can't deal with the cases. We know listwise deletion is in many situations hugely problematic, even if a lot of records would be left, so you usually need to handle the missing data first in some way you think is appropriate.
